# Panel Match: ATT estimate level of significance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, panel-data

I am a novice user in R. I'm working with Version 1.3.1093 and Windows .

I'm working on a Panel Data Set for all activist interventions by hedge funds in Europe for the period 2005 - 2019(time variable). So I have data on a firm-year level. I created an ID Variable, giving a number to each company. I already calculated some financial ratios for each firm-year: Roa, Ebitda margin, Sales growth, Leverage, etc.

With Panel Match package, I am estimating the average treatment on treated (ATT) matching the treatment group of firms with the control one.

If I run the code  `summary(resultsinquestions)` it gives me the: estimate, the standard errors and the 95% CI of the ATT for each year under analysis. My question is: how can I test the level of significance for each estimate?